# How to test tire indexed_json results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I would like to test my search method but how to test `to_indexed_json` results.

Here is my test:

```
describe Search do
  before do
    Question.index.delete
    Question.tire.create_elasticsearch_index
    app = create :app, name: "Marketing", id: 76
    @question1 = create :question, content: "Some super question?", app: app
    @question2 = create :question, content: "Some extra question?", app: app
  end

  describe "#results" do
    it "returns matched results" do
      Search.new("Some", \[76\]).results.should == \[@question1, @question2\]
    end
  end
end
```

And this is error which I receive:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not really testing `to_indexed_json` in the posted code -- you're testing some expectations about search results. That's fine, and actually more reasonable thing to do :), but still a different thing.

Second, in integration tests, be sure to call the `Tire::Index#refresh` after you index test data, so they are immediately available to search -- the default delay is 1 second.

Third, you're creating some test models in your code, and then expect these exact objects to be returned. To make *Tire* behave like this, use the `:load => true` option (to load the models from the database), *or* do not set expectations about object equivalence, but test eg. some property of your model (eg. `content`).